# Как добавить объект из библиотеки на сцену? ActionScript 2.0

Tags: actionscript

Как добавить объект из библиотеки на сцену? ActionScript 2.0

Comment: @Darkhonion, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Убедиться, что для клипа в библиотеке в свойствах стоит галочка "Export for ActionScript" и имя для экземляра. Далее добавить через [`MovieClip.AttachMovie()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001278.html)

```
this.attachMovie("linkageLibraryName", "instance", this.getNextHighestDepth());
```

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно должен выглядеть код для кнопки?